# How is screenshots slideshow implemented in App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, slideshow

I really like the slideshow of application screenshots in application info in App Store. Does anyone have an idea how it is implemented? May be there are some tutorials or source code available? I could not find any.

May be not exactly the same, but something similar, where user can slide images in imageView would be very good

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this tutorial, using a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`.

http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like a standard UIScrollView, with pagingEnabled set to YES, hosting a couple of smaller UIImageViews arranged in a row.